# How do I correctly implement DNS and redirects from subdomain to domain

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, 301-redirect

We are updating our website (example.co.uk) part of which involves setting up 301 redirects from the old site, in the .htaccess file — which is fine and straightforward.

The old site had an area that used a subdomain (xyz.example.co.uk) which was pointed to a third-party platform.

The new site now incorporates that area (on several different pages) so the subdomain is no longer required. For best practice and to preserve any SEO juice from existing links, what is the best course of action? I have spent hours looking online for answers but cannot find anything that gives me the confidence to implement.

From an SEO standpoint we ideally want to 301 redirect the old pages as follows:
https://xyz.example.co.uk/page1 to https://example.co.uk/page2
https://xyz.example.co.uk/page2/page3 to https://example.co.uk/page4/page5
Etc…
However, I understand that placing these in the .htaccess file (on the main domain server) will not work, as we're trying to go from subdomain to domain?

Firstly, do we need the DNS entry for the subdomain anymore? Or does it have to remain in place? The subdomain is currently a CNAME but can I change it to an A record and point to the same IP as the main domain?

I have considered many options (FYI the hosting is with Cloudways — Digital Ocean and the DNS is managed via CloudFlare):

A) Not worry about the page to page 301 redirects and instead add the following in the main domain .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.example.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/page/ [R=301,L]
```

But is this bad for SEO?

B) Do nothing with the redirect and just point the subdomain at the main domain using an A record, then take a hit with the SEO.

C) Set up a page rule in Cloudflare and forward https://xyz.example.co.uk/* to https://example.co.uk/page — in which case I assume I would need to keep the subdomain DNS entry? However, should it be changed to an A record and point to the main domain server IP?

I think I've confused myself enough now, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for SEO is to 301 redirect subdomain URLs to new URLs.

You need to have a DNS entry for `xyz.example.co.uk` so that people can resolve the server's IP address.

Then you need to have a HTTP server running on that IP address to serve the redirects you need. In your case, it can be the same server as you currently use for the main site (provided that the hosting provider supports subdomain setups).

In the HTTP server you need to have a virtual server defined for `xyz.example.co.uk`, which would then contain the redirect rules you want to use.

You need to also make sure that `https://xyz.example.co.uk` has a valid TLS certificate installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

SEO optimisation is more a topic  for the [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site.

Technically:

> Firstly, do we need the DNS entry for the subdomain anymore?

You need *a* DNS entry for the subdomain `xyz.example.co.uk` to remain for any kind of redirect to be able to exist. Without that DNS entry any request for xyz.example.com will fail with an "host not found" or similar DNS error...

[image: google domain not found]
[image: safari domain not found]

For redirection to take place in web browsers there needs to be a webserver running on whatever host you point the `xyz.example.co.uk` subdomain to.

If you have a HSTS policy and/or the old subdomain was also available on HTTPS, you need to configure that web server with a valid SSL certificate for `xyz.example.co.uk` as well.

If you point the `xyz.example.co.uk` subdomain to the same web server that is used for your main website (for instance with a CNAME record) you have two options:

- You create an additional "VirtualHost" entry specifically for  `xyz.example.co.uk`
  (my recommended solution as that keeps the configuration nice and separate)
- You handle the requests for `xyz.example.co.uk` in the existing `www.example.com` website. Then:

  - either you don't do any special handling and then `http://xyz.example.co.uk` will display the `http://www.example.com` index page and a request for `http://xyz.example.co.uk/page2/page3` will display the page `http://www.example.co.uk/page2/page3` if it exists or your 404 error page when it does not.
  - alternatively you configure rewrite rules that trigger when `xyz.example.co.uk` is used to access your site and do the kind of redirecting that you can also do from a separate VirtualHost

The most simple configuration in Apache style (since you were talking about the abomination that is the `.htaccess` file ) uses the [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive which will rewrite requests for either `http://` or `https://xyz.example.com/service/foo.txt` to `https://www.example.com/service/foo.txt` :

```
# existing VirtualHost for www.example.com 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername www.example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername www.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/conf/ssl/www.example.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/conf/ssl/www.example.com.key"
    ...
</VirtualHost>

# new minimal VirtualHost entries for xyz.example.co.uk
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername xyz.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername xyz.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.example.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.example.com.key"
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Always start testing your redirects with a temporary redirect as permanent redirects are cached by your browser which makes correcting any mistakes difficult.

Since you already mentioned that content from the old subdomain won't be found on the some location the `Redirect` directive above might not be the best solution.

Instead you could chose to redirect all old URI's to single landing page (explaining that XYZ has been deprecated, please explore the new site using this site map.) with a the [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive:

```
# new minimal VirtualHost entries for xyz.example.co.uk
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername xyz.example.com
    RedirectMatch "*" "https://www.example.com/xyz-is-deprecated.html"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername xyz.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.example.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etcl/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.example.com.key"
    RedirectMatch "*" "https://www.example.com/xyz-is-deprecated.html"
</VirtualHost>
```

The most labor intensive is to map every old page on the xyz subdomain to new pages on your main website. That can be done with for example the [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) directive.

The most simple mapping is a text file that maps the old URI path to a new URI path, for example a map file: `/etc/apache2/xyz-to-www.txt`

```
##
## xyz-to-www.txt - Map old URI's from xyz.example.com to 
##                  corresponding URI's on www.example.com
##
/             /xyz-is-deprecated.html
/page1        /page2 
/page2/page3  /page4/page5
```

And then this will map `http(s)://xyz.example.co.uk/page1` to `https://www.example.co.uk/page2` and anything that is not mapped will be redirected to the page `https://www.example.com/yz-is-deprecated.html` :

```
# new minimal VirtualHost entries for xyz.example.co.uk
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername xyz.example.com
    RewriteMap xyz-to-www "txt:/etc/apache2/xyz-to-www.txt"
    RewriteRule "(.*)" "https://www.example.com${xyz-to-www:$1}" [R]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername xyz.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.example.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etcl/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.example.com.key"
    RewriteMap xyz-to-www "txt:/etc/apache2/xyz-to-www.txt"
    RewriteRule "(.*)" "https://www.example.com${xyz-to-www:$1|/xyz-is-deprecated.html}" [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Note: all the above is untested and only intended to illustrate the concepts.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)